# How do I create a generic page for all my Spring controller exceptions?

Tags: spring, exception, custom-error-pages

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE.  I’m trying to set up a JSP as a catch-all page for any exceptions originating from my controllers.  However, the mechanism isn’t kicking in.  I have added this to my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>subco Application</display-name>
    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <path>/myproject</path>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-myproject.xml,
            classpath:/META-INF/spring/infrastructure.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config</param-name>
        <param-value>csrfguard.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config.Print</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.mainco.subco.myproject.mvc.listener.SbSessionAttributeListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.servlet.JavaScriptServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>source-file</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/csrfguard.js</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>inject-into-forms</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>inject-into-attributes</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>domain-strict</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/csrfjs</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyprojectDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/jboss-as-spring-mvc-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyprojectDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyprojectDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and created the error.jsp in my WEB-INF directory.  However, when exceptions are generated from within my controllers, e.g. NullPointerExceptions, I do not see the error.jsp page, but rather a generic spring message that reads, ‘{“status":"failure","exception":"NullPointerException”}’.  What other configurations do I need to do to engage my generic error page?  I’m using JBoss 7.1.3.Final if that matters.

**Edit:**

Here is the application context file, referenced in the web.xml file from above:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco.assessment.mvc"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco.myproject.mvc"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco.myproject.validator"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco.standards.mvc"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco.resource.mvc"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco.registration"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco.section.mvc" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco.user.mvc" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco.util.mvc" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco.security" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco.myproject.lti" /> 

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:core.properties,classpath:application.properties"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:MyprojectUserMessages"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="10000000" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:order="3" p:defaultErrorView="error" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use in your web.xml like this:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Are you using Spring MVC? If so, try config an exception resolver in your mvc application context, something like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:order="3" p:defaultErrorView="error" />
```

Your error.jsp must be in the path of your `viewResolver` (e.g. `"WEB-INF/pages"`, `"WEB-INF/views"`, etc.).

PS.: to use p:* you have add xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" in your beans, something like this:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- your configs go here -->

</beans>
```

You can also use [@ExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) and/or a [@ControllerAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice) with Spring MVC.

Comment: I changed my web.xml directive to be "<location>/WEB-INF/error.jsp</location>" and also added the "<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:order="3" p:defaultErrorView="error" />" to my application context file, but still no dice.

Comment: @DaveA can you share your application?

Comment: Done!  I added the web.xml file and the associated context file into my question.

Comment: @DaveA see this link: http://goo.gl/cK1yu9. As you can see I did two ways: with controller advice and SimpleMappingExceptionResolver. You can comment one or another and test.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but was still unable to invoke my error page.  I noticed that your "ControllerErrorHandle" class has no methods, not sure if that's important or not.

Comment: @DaveA As said, comment one or another and test. ControllerErrorHandler has only one method and was commented. Uncommented it, try again. Test the project as is and see how it works, then make changes in yours.